# How do I build against the UCRT with mingw-w64?

Tags: mingw-w64, universal-crt

I would like to be able to use mingw-w64 to build binaries that link to the Universal CRT available with Visual Studio 2015+ instead of MSVCRT.lib. The [release notes for mingw-w64 v6.0.0](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/36416777/) include the following: "Massive additions to support UCRT thanks to Martin Storsjö"

Unfortunately my searches have not revealed the documentation on how to use this support.

Does anyone know what options I need to supply and where to supply them?

Comment: mingw-w64 uses gcc which does not link with msvcrt (proprietary).

Comment: @Biswapriyo - I'm aware this has been the case in past versions of mingw-w64, but the release notes for the latest version (linked in the question) mention UCRT support.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it, but there is some information at the [mingw-w64 mailinglist](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/mingw-w64-public/thread/12e05577525941149af35a3e5cb7fa66%40vector.com/).

Comment: `$ gcc -mcrtdll=ucrt ...` worked for **linking** against the UCRT but the option doesn't define any of the `_UCRT*` macros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I have done it along with **VS 2017**. But as far as I understand both **VS 2015** and **VS 2017** use the `VCRUNTIME140.DLL`, so no worries here.

It is divided into two steps:

### 1. Creating an import library for `VCRUNTIME140.DLL`:

This is done by doing the following:

```
mkdir scratch; cd scratch
cp C:/Windows/System32/vcruntime140.dll .
dumpbin /exports vcruntime140.dll > exports.txt
echo LIBRARY VCRUNTIME140 > vcruntime140.def
echo EXPORTS >> vcruntime140.def
tail +20 exports.txt | head -n -10 | awk '{print $4}' >> vcruntime140.def
lib /def:vcruntime140.def /out:libvcruntime140.a /machine:x86
cp libvcruntime140.a $(MINGW_ROOT)/i686-w64-mingw32/lib
```

### 2. Change the way **MinGW GCC** operates to link against `VCRUNTIME140` and `UCRT` instead of `MSVCRT`

```
gcc -dumpspecs > $(MINGW_ROOT)/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/$(GCC_VERSION)/specs
```

1. Add `-D_UCRT` to `cpp` and `cc1plus` sections of the specs file. This will prevent undefined references linking errors for the `scanf` functions family. Check my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838633/location-of-scanf-function-family-in-vc-runtime-2017-to-be-used-in-mingw-7).
2. Replace `-lmsvcrt` to `-lvcruntime140 -lucrt` in the `libgcc` section of the specs file.

---

Please exchange `$(MINGW_ROOT)` with the location of where u have **MinGW**.

Notes:

- The platform signature part, `i686-w64-mingw32`, within the paths I included may differ for your case. I believe based on the architecture. So you may have to modify that accordingly.
- You need to use a relatively new **MinGW** that has `libucrt.a` in the *$(MINGW_ROOT)/i686-w64-mingw32/lib* folder. I am using **MinGW 7.0.0** with **GCC 7.4.0**.

Comment: Two notes about this: 1) You don't need to use vcruntime140.dll, so the whole step 1 can be skipped. Just remove `-lvcruntime140`, `-lucrt` is enough. vcruntime140.dll isn't shipped as part of the UCRT itself but can be bundled with the app (or may or may not be installed somewhere in a system directory) 2) When compiling C code and not linking any prebuilt static libraries (outside of the default libmingw32.a and libmingwex.a) this works, but other prebuilt libraries can depend on details that differ significantly between CRT versions.

Comment: In particular - libstdc++ probably depends a lot on the CRT it was built for - so you can't use a prebuilt libstdc++ that was built for msvcrt.dll and link it against UCRT. (Or it may seem to work and give tricky latent bugs.) So this approach of adding `-D_UCRT` and replacing `-lmsvcrt` with `-lucrt` works if you don't use prebuilt libraries including libstdc++ and build everything else from scratch. The safest approach is to rebuild the whole toolchain from scratch with `--with-default-msvcrt=ucrt` passed to mingw-w64-headers and mingw-w64-crt.

Comment: Yes, exactly I have built MinGW crt and headers with `--with-default-msvcrt=ucrt` and used them during compilation of GCC as well as all the libs that I have added afterwards. About vcruntime140 yes it is not necessary.