# Location of scanf function family in VC runtime 2017 to be used in MinGW 7

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2017, mingw

I am using:

- VS 2017
- MinGW with GCC/G++ 7.4.0.

Basically what is happening goes as follows:

1. An executable is built using VS 2017
2. An .so is built with GCC
3. The .so is loaded by the executable created in step 1

The issue stems from the `MSVCRT`. **MinGW** by default links against `MSVCRT.DLL` and the executable created using **VS 2017** uses `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` and `UCRTBASE.DLL`.

When the `.so` is loaded two CRT exist the one from `MSVCRT.DLL` and the other from `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` and `UCRTBASE.DLL`. This causes random issues/memory issues during application runtime.

The solution for that is to have **MinGW** link against `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` instead of `MSVCRT.DLL`. I have done that by creating an import library from `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` added it to **MinGW** and dumped the **GCC** specs and modified it to have it link to the `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` and `UCRTBASE.DLL`.

My problem now is the `scanf` family functions. I can't seem to find the scanf functions within `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` or `UCRTBASE.DLL`.

Where does the `scanf` family lie now in the whole new **UCRT** thing?

So, I just compiled a small test application which makes use of `scanf` and compiled it using **VS 2017** and found that it uses **API-MS-WIN-CRT-STDIO-L1-1-0.DLL** which then uses **UCRTBASE.DLL** for `scanf` which appears this way `__stdio_common_vscanf`.

I am now so confused. Is there any kind of a clean way to reference `scanf` functions by **MinGW GCC**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the undefined `scanf` errors during linking by only adding `-D_UCRT` to **cpp** and **cc1plus** parts of the **GCC** spec file.

I reached this solution after checking the sources found in stdio folder of mingw `src\mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\stdio` and some threads in the discussion forum of **MinGW** sourceforge.

**MinGW** `stdio.h` had `#ifdef _UCRT` around `scanf` related functions.