# Can't use c32rtomb on MinGW, even though header is included

Tags: c, mingw, linker-errors, mingw-w64

I have a project I made on Linux where I use the `c32rtomb` function found in `uchar.h`, and it works fine on Linux.

But when I tried porting my project to windows using MinGW, I get this error:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'c32rtomb'
```

So I look into the `uchar.h` file to see if the function declaration is even there, and I find this:

```
#ifdef _UCRT

size_t mbrtoc16 (char16_t *__restrict__ pc16,
         const char *__restrict__ s,
         size_t n,
         mbstate_t *__restrict__ ps);

size_t c16rtomb (char *__restrict__ s,
         char16_t c16,
         mbstate_t *__restrict__ ps);

size_t mbrtoc32 (char32_t *__restrict__ pc32,
         const char *__restrict__ s,
         size_t n,
         mbstate_t *__restrict__ ps);

size_t c32rtomb (char *__restrict__ s,
         char32_t c32,
         mbstate_t *__restrict__ ps);

#endif  /* _UCRT */
```

And then I try defining `_UCRT` before including `uchar.h` so that the declarations are written.

But now I get a linking error:

```
undefined reference to `c32rtomb'
```

It seems that the function isn't in the libc of MinGW?

MinGW version 1.20.0 downloaded through w64devkit

Comment: Does [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57528555/694733) help? Please note that I am only guessing, and have never tried this myself.